# можно ли в таблице БД собирать значения из колонок и записывать их в одну?

Tags: postgresql

Можно ли в PostgreSQL собирать значения из всех колонок и записывать их в одну?
Типо, есть 4 колонки. В первых 3-х есть значения, а в 4-ую их надо записать вместе с помощью DEFAULT. Что-то вроде: "значение 1-го столбца" + "значение 2-го" + "значение 3-го".
К примеру: Столбец 1 содержит - `Hello`; Столбец 2 - `,` ; Столбец 3 - `World!`, а в четвёртом получится - `Hello, World!`
Надеюсь, понятно)

Comment: в Postgres 12  можно... в версиях  ниже только с помозью отдельной функции и триггера на вставку/апдейт

Comment: Это называется вычисляемое поле (generated column). Почитайте в справке.

Comment: @Akina, благодарю)